# What type of things create electric fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge

Magnets create magnetic fields, but what creates electric fields? If this question is too broad, I can elaborate as much as people want.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is only one electric field and only one magnetic field.   A magnet can *alter* the magnetic field.  So can a moving charged particle.  A charged particle can alter the electric field.  So can a moving magnet.  Maxwell's equations give the full picture.